# Auto closing tags for Edge templating engine on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have installed Auto Closing Tags and IntelliSenses, but I can't make the VS Code auto complete the tags on .edge files. I also have Edge template support
extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your VSCode like that:

```
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
  "edge"
],
```